# obtain corresponding values from 3rd column after groupby 2 columns

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

The following code groups max values of 'time' per category.
I would like to obtain the corresponding value in the 'target' variable but I am not sure how to do it.
Any hints?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data=[[1,1,2,2,'A'],
      [2,5,5,1,'A'],
      [3,7,9,4,'B'],
      [1,5,1,9,'B'],
      [1,8,2,8,'C'],
      [2,8,5,10,'C'],
      [0,1,2,3,'D']]

df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['time','x','y','target','categ'])
res = ((df.groupby('categ')['time'].max().value_counts(ascending=True).sort_index()))
print(res)
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) + [`groupby idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html):

```
res = df.loc[
    df.groupby('categ')['time'].idxmax(),
    ['time', 'target']
].sort_values('time')['target']
```

`res`:

```
6     3
1     1
5    10
2     4
Name: target, dtype: int64
```

---

Or filter with [`groupby transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) max if all rows which match the group maximum are wanted:

```
res = df.loc[
    df.groupby('categ')['time'].transform('max').eq(df['time']),
    ['time', 'target']
].sort_values('time')['target']
```

`res`:

```
6     3
1     1
5    10
2     4
Name: target, dtype: int64
```

*Output is the same in this case, but will not be if there are duplicate maximal values per `categ`.

---

Per the comments with [`groupby agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) on `time` and aggregate into list:

```
res = df.groupby('time')['target'].agg(list)
```

`res`:

```
time
0          [3]
1    [2, 9, 8]
2      [1, 10]
3          [4]
Name: target, dtype: object
```

Comment: thank you. Similarly, the code line for all entries in 'time' is this one: time_count=(df['time'].value_counts(ascending=True).sort_index())
print(time_count). How do you obtain the target values in this case ?

Comment: for time=1, target =2,9,8 . for time=2, target=1,10 etc... I would like to print these group of target values because afterwards I want to divide the sum of all target values for which time is max for a given categ by all target values for each time value. I am sorry if I am a bit confusing but is not very easy to explain. I hope I have been clear.

Comment: Yes, pretty much

Comment: this line res = df.groupby('time')['target'].agg(list) prints in time ascending order but this line res = df.loc[
    df.groupby('categ')['time'].transform('max').eq(df['time']),
    'target'  does not. How do you make sure that this line prints in ascending order too ?

Comment: neither sort values nor sort index work. It should be sorted time wise. It should print 3,2,1,10,4 since  categ=3 corresponds to time=0,categ 2 corresponds to time=1 and so on

Comment: I don't understand will you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68505255/edit) to _show_ what output you're looking for and why.

Comment: you already have answered to all my questions. All I need now is just to print the output of that line in time ascending order. The output should be [3,2,1,10,4]. I am not sure if the 1 goes before or after the 10 since they both correspond to time=2

Comment: Again, I'm sorry, but I do not understand where that order comes from.

Comment: it comes from the value of time. When time=0, target=3. when time=2, target=10,1 and when time=3, target=4. Therefore I would like to print [3,10,1,4]

Comment: Understood. You can grab both the time and the target column with loc. Sort then sort by time. See code block 1 and 2. I ended up with 1 then 10 I hope that's okay. I understand what you were staying earlier now.

Answer (score 0):

In your case do `drop_duplicates` after `sort_values`

```
df.sort_values(['time']).drop_duplicates(['categ'],keep='last')['target']
Out[184]: 
6     3
1     1
5    10
2     4
Name: target, dtype: int64
```

Or do `transform` when a group of categ have all same value , this method will output all of them

```
df.loc[df.time.eq(df.groupby('categ').time.transform('max')),'target']
Out[187]: 
1     1
2     4
5    10
6     3
Name: target, dtype: int64
```